# Numpy way of building an irregular array of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-slicing

Let's assume I have a huge (actually, it would have around a ~1_000_000 values) numpy array of floats.

```
data = np.arange(100).astype(np.float64)
```

In parallel I created two numpy arrays of integers (that would be indices later on)

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
b = np.array([10,20,30,40,50,60,70])
```

Right now I need to create (efficiently, i.e., using numpy vectorised notations and operations) a numpy array of slices defined by `a` (as a starting index) and `b` (as a finishing index) from `data`.
The output should be something like this:

```
[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19],
...]
```

This will be needed to sum the inner array for further calculations.

I looked into `np.take` function, but it looks that it doesn't suit my needs... Does anyone have some idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "This will be needed to sum the inner array for further calculations." - rather than trying to build a ragged array, you might want to look at [`reduceat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html).

Comment: Or, considering how sums work, you could just build a cumulative sum array with [`numpy.cumsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) and then subtract appropriate elements to get your final results.

Comment: An 'irregular array of arrays' is really a list of arrays.  Even the `np.split` makes such a list, iteratively slicing.  But if the sums are more important than the arrays then others have suggested tools.